# How can I .filter an object by elements within an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I've been playing around trying to learn in an API project using Postman and conducting tests using JavaScript. So far, I have succeeded with the help of reading on websites and watching YouTube videos. Of course, previous tests and playing around have been fairly easy but now I came to a stop. I really tried to figure this out for several weeks but I need further guidance, a push in the right direction or direct help.

What I'm trying to do is to filter out some of the response to only view objects that contain specific data.

To do that, I'm using a filter where I want all products containing a specific value inside an array "product_option_values".

My first approach was to see if I could sort products having any values from the first array, and it worked. It filters just fine.

```
var filterSmall = jsonData.products.filter(fs => fs.associations.product_option_values);
```

My next approach was to get to my goal of filtering out products according to specific values inside this array. I tried many simple .(dot) combinations and pointing to [index] to access it without any luck. (I must add that I know how to access this from a specific product, but that way doesn't work when filtering).

I've also tried other approaches such as:

```
var filterSmall = jsonData.products.filter(fs => fs.associations["product_option_values", 0, "name"] === "S");
```

and other similar combinations.

This is a very shortened sample of the structure of "products" which in its full form consists of 20 products and far more values inside of it:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "id": 16,
        "manufacturer_name": "Graphic Corner",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "12.900000",
        "indexed": "1",
        "name": "Mountain fox notebook",
        "associations": {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6"
                }
            ],
            "product_option_values": [
                {
                    "id": "22"
                },
                {
                    "id": "23"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "manufacturer_name": "Graphic Corner",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "12.900000",
        "indexed": "1",
        "name": "Brown bear notebook",
        "associations": {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6"
                }
            ],
            "product_option_values": [
                {
                    "id": "23"
                },
                {
                    "id": "24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

and here is a small and expanded sample from product_option_values:

```
{
"product_option_values": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "0",
        "name": "S"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "1",
        "name": "M"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "2",
        "name": "L"
    }
]
```

}

How do I proceed? Did I do anything correct or even close to it?

Perhaps I've been staring at this for too long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the `small sample from product_option_values` array relate to the original `products` array? Are they different things, or is the former an expanded version of what's actually in the latter?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it, it's an expanded version only.

Comment: So, the goal is to filter the products to produce the subset of products that has one or more `product_option_values` with a name of "S" (representing small)?

Comment: The goal is to filter how many products that have specific values from product_option_values. For example how many products have the product_option_values.id 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare nested attributes you have to transform the objects (e.g. by using a map operation), so that the relevant attributes are easily accessible for a comparison. If you want to filter by product_option_value id, you could do something like this:

```js
const jsonData = {
"products": [
    {
        "id": 16,
        "manufacturer_name": "Graphic Corner",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "12.900000",
        "indexed": "1",
        "name": "Mountain fox notebook",
        "associations": {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6"
                }
            ],
            "product_option_values": [
                {
                    "id": "22"
                },
                {
                    "id": "23"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "manufacturer_name": "Graphic Corner",
        "quantity": "0",
        "price": "12.900000",
        "indexed": "1",
        "name": "Brown bear notebook",
        "associations": {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6"
                }
            ],
            "product_option_values": [
                {
                    "id": "23"
                },
                {
                    "id": "24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
};

const sample = {
"product_option_values": [
    {
        "id": 22,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "0",
        "name": "S"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "1",
        "name": "M"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "id_attribute_group": "1",
        "color": "",
        "position": "2",
        "name": "L"
    }
]
};

const ids = sample.product_option_values.map((el) => String(el.id));
console.log(ids);

const filtered = jsonData.products.filter((fs) => fs.associations.product_option_values.map((e) => e.id).some((f) => ids.includes(f)));

console.log(filtered);
```